# Repeating a formula in excel for a specific number of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am not sure if the title is clear, but basically I am helping a friend with process his data from a series of readings and I need to get the average of the reading for the day

Each grouping has 143 entries

I have used this formula: `=AVERAGE('20-min'!C####:C#143)`

To get the average of those readings

Where `####` is the start of a day's reading and the end is 143 cells lower

So average of cells `1-143`. Then my next cell must be average of cells `144-287`, but when I drag the formula column down to automate it just averages `###1-#145` Rather than `#144-#287`.

Can anybody tell me what I have done wrong

Comment: Should not the second average be from **144** through **286** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need an **address pattern** that we can propagate downwards.  Pick any cell and enter:

```
="'20-min'!C" & 1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*143 & ":C" & ROWS(1:$1)*143
```

and copy downwards to see:

[image]

Thus the formula we need is:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'20-min'!C" & 1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*143 & ":C" & ROWS(1:$1)*143))
```